# How to deploy android app using phonegap (Cordova) desktop and bootstrap

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, phonegap-build

I tried searching about this before posting but I found no answer that works so I'm asking you help.

I've built a website using bootstrap and I've given it a "app layout". Now, I want to use phonegap (or now cordova) to deploy what I made into a .apk android app...

The documentation that I've searched always was very vast and I'm dearly new at this so, if someone could send some guidance I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The main Phonegap page has all the info you need.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html

Comment: Thanks, I've searched it and found it but didn't know how to apply that knowledge. I've managed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for all the newbies out there with the same strugles a me:

the real problem for me was on how to install the frameworks of cordova and build the app in it since it's not that user friendly for someone who's starting at this...

I've also found a better framework for phone apps called ionic and a very relevant tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLX2FEg0TjU

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is amusing because although I only use Ionic I tried to just answer your question without promotion of other frameworks.